# How to adjust the URL settings when moving a WP site manually to a new host and domain?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, backup, restore

This is my first WP website, in the past I've only dealt with normal html websites which are pretty easy to move around between new hosts and domains.

I'm not using a plug-in to backup and restore, here's what I have so far:

- I backed up all the site files via FTP.
- I backed up the database by using phpMyAdmin and exported my WP site database as an SQL file using the quick method.

This is what I want to do to move the website to the new domain and host:

- Upload files to the new server
- Create new DB and import the site db there using phpmyadmin.
- Edit the wp-config.php file with the new server's database details (name, user).

Now what I'm stuck with is dealing with the URL, would it be enough to just add these lines in the wp-config.php file? :

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

replacing example with the new website url, as mentioned here http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Any help to properly move the website would be much appreciated and would be great if you could let me know if I'm doing something wrong, like for example if I should install a fresh WP first on the new host before moving files and DB to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database will have occurrences of the old url within. You need to *search* and replace the old url and *replace* with the new url. However you can't simply get a text editor and do a find replace as the WordPress db uses serialised arrays. To account for the serialised data use this tool -https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/. You upload this tool to your server and run it by navigating to it's location in your browser. So if you have `http://www.oldurl.com` to `http://www.newurl.com` do find 'oldurl.com', replace 'newurl.com'. When you're done delete the tool as it's a huge security risk.

If you do this you shouldn't need to define urls in your `wp-config.php`. the rest of your steps are fine.

Answer (score 1):

First step should be change the **wp-config.php**

```
define('DB_NAME', 'YOUR DATABASE NAME');
define('DB_USER', 'YOUR DATABASE USER');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'YOUR DATABASE PASSWORD');
define('DB_HOST', 'YOUR HOST');
```

Second step is open up the Sql file in any text-editor (Dreamweaver, Sublime , Netbeans) and find site URL.

Third and final step is find and replace the existing (local URL) to the new URL.

I hope it works !!